# Django raise KeyError(key) From None?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to deploy my project into production but I'm having trouble configuring it up properly. This is the current error I got

```
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\1111\Desktop\2222\2222\settings.py", line 23, in <module>
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
  File "C:\Users\1111\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'

C:\Users\1111\Desktop\2222>
```

line 23 of settings.py

> SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']

Please help , no idea what to do

Ok on wsgi.py I pasted this in

os.environ["SECRET_KEY"] = 'abcdef'

I saved, tried to run again but got same error:

```
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'
```

Ok I tried using "os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY', "default_value")" instead and now it works and I get

"CommandError: You must set settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS if DEBUG is False." instead

Now to fix the above I tried

> ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

in settings.py and it worked!

Comment: Do not use `os.environ['SECRET_KEY']`. Use `os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY', "default_value")`. And define `SECRET_KEY` in environment variable in your server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a SECRET_KEY environment variable, you can do it by following the steps given  [here](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/environment-variables-for-web-apps/)

Comment: If you are using Windows use
    set SECRET_KEY="your_secret_key"

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
password = str(os.environ.get('PASSWORD'))
```

instead of using

```
password = str(os.environ['PASSWORD'])
```